# Como saber se há um CRON realizando o trabalho no coletor de lixo do PHP 5.3 (CentOS)?

Tags: php, centos, cron, garbage-collector

Eu tenho esse erro:

> ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/var/lib/php5) failed: Permission denied.

A correção normal é a definir

```
session.gc_probability = 0
```

Mas em CentOS, o correto é que o `session.gc_probability` seja `1`. 
Se alguém tiver conhecimento sobre, o que pode acontecer se eu alterar para 0 em um servidor CentOS?

Mas a pergunta principal é como descobrir se há realmente um CRON realizando o trabalho (o que não deveria acontecer) e caso alguém saiba, como desativar esse CRON.

Answer (score 0):

Algumas distribuições *nix, principalmente as baseadas em Debian, a diretiva `session.gc_maxlifetime` é ignorada quando setada em tempo de execução.

Isso acontece porque tais distribuições linux desabilitam o coletor de lixo do PHP setando `session.gc_probability=0`.

Para realizar a coleta de lixo, o próprio Sistema Operacional cria um CRONJOB, normalmente rodando a cada 30 minutos. Esse CRONJOB faz a tarefa de coleta do lixo. Para identificar o local e quais sessões devem ser limpas, o script do CRONJOB faz uma leitura do "php.ini". Especificamente, buscam pela diretiva `session.gc_maxlifetime`. Os mais antigos buscam por `session.gc_probability`.

Pela internet, encontrará muitas postagens indicando `session.gc_probability=0` como solução para evitar o erro descrito na pergunta. Porém, isso não funciona em sistemas mais recentes. Antigamente o script buscava por essa diretiva porém, os atuais ignoram e buscam por `session.gc_maxlifetime`. Por isso também é comum ver muitos usuários que dizem que não funciona desativar com `session.gc_probability=0`.

Para uma solução mais eficiente, ajuste o `session.save_path` para um outro local e desative o CRONJOB criado automaticamente pelo SO.

Nesse caso, se o folder escolhido não tiver uma limpeza regular, o lixo acumulará. Você deve criar o seu próprio script e rodá-lo em CRONJOB ou habilitar o próprio coletor do PHP `session.gc_probability=1`.

Para listar os agendamentos do usuário com o qual está logado: `crontab -l`. Entre como root e execute esse comando para ver os agendamentos. Então apenas desabilite o agendamento específico: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011065/enable-disable-tasks-in-crontab-by-bash-shell

> Mas em CentOS, o correto é que o session.gc_probability seja 1. Se
>   alguém tiver conhecimento sobre, o que pode acontecer se eu alterar
>   para 0 em um servidor CentOS?

Não necessariamente. Pode setar como zero. Aí nesse caso deve criar o seu próprio coletor, tal como explicado acima.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Você saberia informar se é possível desativar o CRON pelo painel de controle (Plesk)? Existe alguma forma de checar se o coletor de lixo está configurado corretamente pelo Plesk?

Comment: Plesk? Não vi mencionar Plesk na pergunta. Mas enfim, é possível desde que consiga logar-se no Plesk como root. Basta entrar no Scheduled Tasks que verá algo assim: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5f8n.png  Aquela bolinha verde em baixo do `S` é onde ativa ou desativa.