# Como definir para o valor padrão todas as configurações do PHP?

Tags: php, centos, garbage-collector

Eu tenho um VPS Linux CentOS e a configuração do coletor de lixo está errada.
Preciso corrigir de uma maneira fácil já que tenho muito pouco conhecimento nisso. 
Eu gostaria de saber se há um modo de definir todos as configurações do PHP para o padrão. 
Eu uso o painel de controle Plesk. Há no painel a opção de atualizar o PHP para outra versão, por exemplo de 5.3 para 5.6. Eu gostaria de saber se utilizando essa opção todos valores voltariam para o padrão normal do PHP, que é o que eu preciso. 
Obrigado.

Comment: Agora eu fiquei curioso. Qual versão do PHP você usa?

Comment: Eu uso a versão 5.3 do PHP. E penso em atualizar para a versão 5.6.

Comment: E o que você chama de "errada"? Perigoso quando junta na frase "tenho pouco conhecimento" e afirma que algo é errado. Se tiver como dar mais detalhes, talvez dê para a comunidade ajudar de alguma maneira a mais, além da dúvida principal.

Comment: Vale notar que algumas hospedagens permitem você por um php.ini ou .user.ini próprio na raiz (ou algum sistema equivalente) que é levado em consideração pela execução, depende de como foi configurado e que modalidade de PHP está sendo executada. Dê uma consultada no suporte do hospedeiro. Tem isso também: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/configuration.file.per-user.php

Comment: Eu tenho o seguinte erro: Error: PHP Notice: session_start(): ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/var/lib/php/session) failed: Permission denied (13)

Comment: Este erro diz respeito ao garbage collection. Eu acredito que a configuração esteja em 0, sendo que deveria estar em 1.

Comment: Isso é problema de versão e não de config. Pode até fazer uma gambiarra mudando parâmetro, mas é melhor mudar de versão. Mudar o config do GC nao é solução real. Inclusive, as distros com esse problema e essa versão usam o crontab pra limpar o GC

Comment: Então atualizar para a versão 5.6 resolveria o problema?

Comment: Este erro aparece de hora em hora. A impressão é que estaria sendo realizado um CRON. Já que quando este erro aparece, o servidor fica indisponível e inacessível por alguns instantes ou até minutos, assim como o site que está hospedado nesse VPS também fica indisponível e todas consultas ao banco de dados vão sendo acumuladas. Por isso acredito que seja um erro de configuração. Acho possível que o coletor de lixo esteja configurado para 0 e por isso o PHP está fazendo a coleta de lixo via CRON.

Comment: Esse link pode ajudar em algo, mas não creio que seja esse o problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167257/4793. A sua questão necessita de um diagnóstico mais apurado, o que é inviável fazermos sem acesso ao ambiente e além do mais esse não é o objetivo do site. Você pode fornecer um diagnóstico mais detalhado na pergunta para aumentar chances de solucionar.  A versão 5.3, por exemplo não apresenta esse problema. Inclusive tenho ambiente com Plesk e PHP5.3 rodando normalmente em produção.

Answer (score 0):

Você só precisa obter o arquivo original, [que pode ser obtido aqui](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/php.ini-production), é muito longo para ser publicado aqui no StackOverflow.

Dentro do Plesk deve haver algum local "avançado" para alterar as configurações do PHP.ini, assim basta dar o famoso CTRL + C e CTRL + V. ;)

Se quiser pode fazer isso via SSH, **se tiver conhecimento básico sobre o SSH.**

```
cd /etc/
```

> Acessa a pasta `/etc/` (no caso do Plesk deve ser `/etc/php.d`)

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/php/php-src/master/php.ini-production
```

> Salva o arquivo do GitHub

```
mv php.ini-production php.ini
```

> Renomeia o `php.ini-production` para `php.ini`.

Reinicie o PHP após tal alteração. ;)